# Widget with Image button that starts settings activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, widget

I am trying to make a simple widget with 1 `button`. Pressing this `button` will start android settings activity (for instance `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS`).

What's wrong about my code? What should I do to make it work?

Code snippet:

```
public class WiFiShortcut extends AppWidgetProvider{

//ImageButton imagebutton;
static RemoteViews remoteViews;
public static String ACTION="SetWIFI";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //ComponentName watchWidget;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wifi_shortcut_main );
    Intent cel= new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    //Intent cel = new Intent(context, WiFiShortcut.class);
    cel.setAction(ACTION);
    PendingIntent pcel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, cel,0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bwifi, pcel);
}
```

}

Should I use `onReceive` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Intent cel= new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, cel, 0);

ResolveInfo resolveInfo1 = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(cel, 0);
if(resolveInfo1 != null)
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bwifi, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

started to thinking about this widget with my fried and... he helped me write this code.

```
package com.mbaryla.wifisettings;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WiFiShortcut extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WiFiShortcut.class);

    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));

        Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txt, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

}

It works but only when he compiled this code and started on my phone. 
When I compile it on my computer and strart it on my phone it DOES NOT work...

How is this possible????????
Could it be because Manifest?